# NDWI and Cloud Pixel count

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart, function

I am trying to add the (amount of pixels of) NDWI and Clouds as bands to my image collection. The NDWI works out, but I get stuck when adding the Clouds. The error refers to an incompatible number of bands in the image, but I don´t know where exactly it refers to.

Any ideas?

Similarly I would like to add the cloudfunction to the chart.

Am I doing this right?

```js
//-------FUNCTION NDWI-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var date_start = ee.Date.fromYMD(2016,1,1);
var date_end = ee.Date.fromYMD(2018,12,31);
l8 = l8.filterBounds(aoi).filterDate(date_start,date_end);
var landsat8 = l8
var waterThreshold = 0;
var cloudThreshold = 0;

//-------WATERFUNCTION-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var waterfunction = function(image){
//add the NDWI band to the image
var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B6']).rename('NDWI');
  //get pixels above the threshold
  var water01 = ndwi.gt(waterThreshold);
  //mask those pixels from the image
  image = image.updateMask(water01).addBands(ndwi);
  var area = ee.Image.pixelArea();
  var waterArea = water01.multiply(area).rename('waterArea');
  image = image.addBands(waterArea);
  var stats = waterArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
    geometry: aoi, 
    scale: 30,
  });
  return image.set(stats);
};

var collection = landsat8.map(waterfunction);
print('NDWI',collection);

//-------CLOUDFUNCTION-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var cloudfunction = function(image){
  //add the NDWI band to the image
  var cloud= image.select(['B4','B3','B2']).rename('Clouds');
  //get pixels above the threshold
  var cloud01 = cloud.gt(10500).lt(12000);
  //mask those pixels from the image
  image = image.updateMask(cloud01).addBands(cloud);
  var area = ee.Image.pixelArea();
  var cloudArea = cloud01.multiply(area).rename('cloudArea');
  image = image.addBands(cloudArea);
  var stats = cloudArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
    geometry: aoi, 
    scale: 30,
  });
  return image.set(stats);
};

var collection = landsat8.map(cloudfunction);
print('NDWI + Clouds',collection);


var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: collection.select('waterArea','cloudArea'), 
  region: aoi, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
  scale: 30,
});

print(chart);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code example.

1. Your statement for calculating the `cloud` variable is incorrect. It selects 3 bands `['B4','B3','B2']`, but only specifies 1 band name `'Clouds'`:

```js
var cloud = image.select(['B4','B3','B2']).rename('Clouds');
```

2. When you map `cloudfunction` over your image collection, you overwrite the previously defined `collection` object.

```js
var collection = landsat8.map(waterfunction);
var collection = landsat8.map(cloudfunction);
```

instead you probably want to map both functions over the `landsat8` collection:

```js
var collection = landsat8.map(waterfunction).map(cloudfunction);
```